# Как передать массив и функцию в компонент React с помощью роутинга?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

У меня есть react-redux приложение. С помощью передачи в параметрах компонента Table, я в этом компоненте вызываю dispatch.changeTotal и изменяю состояние приложения:

Добавил роутинг и не понимаю как передавать функцию changeTotal в компонент:

???

**Подскажите как передать параметры и функции в компонент React по средствам роутинга?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться свойством `render` компонента `Route`, в котором вызвать ваш компонент со всеми необходимыми пропсами

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
        <Route
            exact
            path="/page/one"
            render={(props) => 
                <ComponentOne 
                    {...props} 
                    variable={varOne}
                    onSome={funcOne}
                />
            }
        />
        <Route
            exact
            path="/page/two"
            render={(props) => 
                <ComponentTwo
                    {...props} 
                    variable={varTwo}
                    onSome={funcTwo}
                />
            }
        />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое